# Struggling to get wysiwyg working in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg

Trying to get bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails gem working.

The code (HAML):

application.css

```
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap-wysihtml5
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-wysihtml5
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

pages.js (the form I edit is for @page)

```
$(".wysihtml5").each (i, elem) ->
  $(elem).wysihtml5()
```

_form.html.haml

```
= f.text_area :content, class: 'wysihtml5'
```

Checked in the DOM and script is there, but I can't see the editor.

Answer (score 0):

try put an id inside your textarea, I'm not really familiar with coffee or haml.

just call

```
$('#someIdorClass').wysihtml5();
```

check your page source code and see whether the wysiwyg iframe code is there